# How to configure public access web api in envoyproxy?

Tags: kubernetes, microservices, envoyproxy

I am new to envoyproxy and I am getting 'jwt is missing' error while trying to access the endpoint without providing Authorization header.
How can I access the public api without auth header
i.e
http://hostaddress/v1/fares/locations/location?searchTerm=ABC

Below code shows existing clusters already added that uses Jwt auth.

```
 http_filters:
              - name: envoy.filters.http.grpc_http1_bridge
                typed_config: {}
              - name: envoy.filters.http.cors
                typed_config: {}
              - name: envoy.filters.http.jwt_authn
                typed_config:
                  "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.jwt_authn.v3.JwtAuthentication
                  providers:
                    identity_api:
                      issuer: 'null'
                      audiences:
                      - apigw
                      forward: true
                      remote_jwks:
                        http_uri:
                          uri: http://abc.identity.api/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks
                          cluster: identity_api
                          timeout: 1s   
                        cache_duration:
                          seconds: 30
                      from_headers:
                      - name: Authorization
                        value_prefix: "Bearer "
                  rules:
                  - match: { prefix: /v1/newhubs/ }
                  - match: { prefix: / }
                    requires:
                      provider_name: identity_api
              - name: envoy.filters.http.ext_authz
                typed_config:
                  "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.ext_authz.v3.ExtAuthz
                  transport_api_version: V3
                  grpc_service:
                    envoy_grpc:
                      cluster_name: permissions_api_grpc
                    timeout: 3s
                  with_request_body:
                    max_request_bytes: 819200
                    allow_partial_message: true
              - name: envoy.filters.http.router
                typed_config: {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `jwt_authn` matches to all paths via the root path: `match: { prefix: / }`.

Remove the `match: { prefix: / }` entry to only have your `jwt_authn` filter match for `/v1/newhubs/`

Comment: Thanks answering to this question. Is it possible to filter out just single path as we need to match: { prefix: / } for other than that path.

Comment: @Khaan I don't think you can configure an exception as the rules are based on paths. One solution might be to move any protected stuff to /secure and change the filter to that path.